# How to show the \title headings in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, context, context-mkiv

My document is organized as following:

```
\title[Some title]
\section[Section 1]
\section[Section 2]
```

etc.

When I use `\completecontents` command to print a ToC, I only get the section titles (which are numbered) and not the titles (`\title` entries). Is there a way to tell ConTeXt to print `\title` entries into ToC? Ideally, I prefer a table of contents that looks something like this:

> **Some Title**
>
> 1. Section 1  xx  2. Section 2 yy
>
> **Another Title**
>
> 1. Section in second title zz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Thanks. It was my first attempt in posting a question and I didn't know that. Now, I know.

Comment: No worries, you'll soon get used to the format of tex.sx, which is a bit different from normal forums. We'll gladly help you along the way. (I don't know any ConTeXt, so I can't help you with your question, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete compileable example of what you want.

```
\setuphead[title][
    incrementnumber=yes, % keep an internal title counter+list
    number=no]  % don't display the counter

% Manually specify the composition of the section and subsection numbers
\setuphead[section][sectionsegments=section]
\setuphead[subsection][sectionsegments=section:subsection]   

% Redefine the toc list to include titles
\definecombinedlist[content][title, section]

\starttext
    % Place the toc
    \placecontent

    % Place some sections to see what their numbers look like.
    \title{T1}
      \section{S1}
        \subsection{Sb1.1}
        \subsection{Sb1.2}
      \section{S2}
        \subsection{Sb2.1}

    \title{T1}
      \section{S1}
        \subsection{Sb1.1}
\stoptext
```

I got the `sectionsegments` key [from phg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62399/2229). For examples on styling the ToC, see the ConTeXt Garden wiki article on the table of contents, section [Modifying the default ToC](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents#Modifying_the_default_Table_of_Contents).

Comment: Thank you @Esteis for the providing the solution. It achieves *almost* what I had in mind with a small caveat: since `\title` now has a number, the sections inherit this number and show up as 1.1, 1.2, etc. Since, this is a lab book that I am writing, I prefer to have just the section numbers and do not append the `\title` numbers to them. I am fairly new to the world of ConTeXt, but I am pretty sure one can setup the sections using `\setuphead` so that the sections do not inherit the chapter or title numbers. I just don't know how. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Caramdir for editing the answer. As much I tried the "Add Comment" button was showing up under the original answer. That's why I started a new answer. Is there a way to delete my answer now that it shows up as a comment?

Comment: @Hooman: It already is. Please register so that you won't lose your login again (and thus keep being able to comment).