# How to set section numbers to use whole numbers, rather than decimals, in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, context, context-mkiv

I have a document like this:

```
\setuphead[part][placehead=yes]

\definestructureresetset[default][1, 0, 1, 0][1]
\setuphead[sectionresetset=default]

\starttext
    \part{Animals}
        \chapter{Birds}
            \section{Parrot}
            \section{Pelican}
                \subsection{Australian Pelican}
                \subsection{Great White Pelican}
        \chapter{Crabs}
            \section{Spider Crab}
    \part{Trees}
        \chapter{Coniferous}
            \section{Pine}
\stoptext
```

After compiling, the sectioning appears like this:

```
1 Animals
    1.1 Birds
        1.1.2 Pelican
            1.1.2.1 Australian Pelican
```

I need to change the numbering so that it uses whole numbers and no decimals, like this:

```
1 Animals
    1 Birds
        2 Pelican
            1 Australian Pelican
```

I checked the ConTeXt Garden's instructions for `\definehead`, `\setuphead`, and `\setupheads`, but could not find a solution.

How can I set section numbers for all titles to use whole numbers, rather than decimals?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61698/compound-nested-section-numbers-in-context-how-to-omit-the-top-level-e-g-1-2. The desired outcome is slightly different, but the qestion/answer is essentially the same.

Comment: Will other people searching for this problem recognize that this supposedly "duplicate" question answers their question?

Comment: Not always, which is why it is policy to keep both the old and the new question around. All that ‘flag as duplicate’ does, AFAIK, is add a note to one question pointing to the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sectionsegments` key. The value is the section element you want to
display. You can use a single value or more than one, separated by a colon,
e.g. `chapter:section`.

```
\setuphead [part] [placehead=yes,page=no]

\setuphead [chapter]    [sectionsegments=chapter]
\setuphead [section]    [sectionsegments=section]
\setuphead [subsection] [sectionsegments=subsection]

\starttext
    \part{Animals}
        \chapter{Birds}
            \section{Parrot}
            \section{Pelican}
                \subsection{Australian Pelican}
                \subsection{Great White Pelican}
        \chapter{Crabs}
            \section{Spider Crab}
    \part{Trees}
        \chapter{Coniferous}
            \section{Pine}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]