# Suppress part and chapter number in headings on LaTeX

Tags: sectioning

I would like to have headings for sections and subsections in the body of the document, where the numbers in the heading show only the "section" or "subsection" level, and do not show the numbers for the part and chapter level at the beginning.

So, for exapmle, instead of II.1.2.3., I just want 2.3.

I found a threat for ConTeX for this issue, but no solution for LaTeX yet. This is the link:
[Compound/nested section numbers in ConTeXt: how to omit the top level? E.g. 1.2.1 --> 2.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61698/compound-nested-section-numbers-in-context-how-to-omit-the-top-level-e-g-1-2)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Perhaps `counterwithout` could be useful here? Could you provide a small [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) for us to play with- the `documentclass` is particularly important

Answer (score 1):

As **cmhughes** said, it is important to know the documentclass, however, presuming you are dealing with a class that has chapters (say book or report), normally the number format makes recursive calls like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

This comes from the fact that when a counter is created via:

```
\newcounter{XXX}
```

A macro `\theXXX` is also created. This macro (`\theXXX`) is responsible for how the counter is formated / displayed. `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `figure`, `table`, etc... are all examples of counters used in the most basic documents, which also have corresponding formatting commands (`\thechapter`, `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, `\thesubsubsection`, `\thefigure` and `\thetable`, respectively) These macro can be redefined, it doesn't alter the value of the counter, only the way it is typeset in the document, including making reference (if one wishes) to other counters, as is the nature of your query.

In the above demonstration of the typical recursive call, `thesubsection` label calls `thesection`, which in turn also calls `thechapter`. So therefore, if you are not interested in having `thechapter` as part of your numbering schema, renew `thesection` to something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Incidentally, if you prefer letters, or roman numerals, for a counter `XXX`, the display format also has several options, for numbers, letters, roman numerals, here are the options:

```
\arabic{XXX}= 1,2,3,...
\alph{XXX}  = a,b,c,...
\Alph{XXX}  = A,B,C,...
\roman{XXX} = i,ii,iii,iv,...
\Roman{XXX} = I,II,III,IV,...
```

Here is a MWE which you can run.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}


\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output, showing how `\thesection` makes no reference to `\thechapter`, as your initial question proposed.

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! It did work out very nicely, and with such a simple solution!

Comment: @Danji. No problem!